# addClass and removeClass when in viewport

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a timeline that has a date element that becomes visible when in viewport. here's a link - http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/timeline/indexl.html

My problem is in the jQuery. I'm a beginner with jQuery and I'm not sure what's wrong. There are no errors detected, but I want it to reveal the date associated with the element in the viewport. Right now, I think the jQuery is having trouble removing the class .hide-date, which has display: none; Thanks for helping!

The jQuery:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function monitor(event, visible) {    
                if (visible) {
                    $('.date-wrapper').window(function() {
                    $(this).find('time').removeClass('hide-date');
                });

                } else {
                    $(this).addClass('hide-date');
                }
            }



                var updateMarker = function() {
                    // Update measurements
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
                        contentHeight = $('#content1').height(),
                        pathWidth = $('#path').width(),
                        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

                    // Update #marker dimensions
                    $('.animate').width(scrollPosition/(contentHeight-viewportHeight)*pathWidth); 
                    // The breakdown: The line of code above defines scrollable distance by:
                    // Subtracting height of #content1 from height of viewport using (contentHeight-viewportHeight)
                    //This determines what percentage of the scroll has been scrolled through
                    // Multiply this percentage by #path width using *pathWidth
                }

                // Calls function when viewport is resized or scrolled    
                $(window).on('scroll resize', updateMarker);

                // Calls function on DOM ready
                updateMarker();
            });
        </script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
        <!-- HTML Code for Timeline elements -->
        <div id='timeline'> <!-- Timeline's main container -->
            <div id='path'></div><!-- Timeline's inner path -->
            <div id='marker' class='animate'></div><!-- Timeline's animatable marker -->
        </div>



        <div id='content1'>
            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='1997-12'>Dec '97</time>
            </div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dolor turpis, consectetur vel libero a, mollis dapibus odio. Nunc lobortis, eros non tincidunt porttitor, purus tellus porta lectus, non luctus arcu augue eu est. Nunc malesuada ex elit, vel bibendum erat dictum nec. Proin imperdiet efficitur elit eu vestibulum. Nullam id augue tincidunt, efficitur nunc non, efficitur urna. Proin sit amet tincidunt purus. Sed interdum, felis quis facilisis malesuada, felis felis viverra lectus, eget euismod elit risus et mi. Mauris eu enim tellus. Aenean tincidunt orci nec tincidunt facilisis. Phasellus dignissim ante ut maximus feugiat. Mauris sollicitudin venenatis neque nec luctus. Quisque vel tempus urna, sed feugiat leo. Sed tellus magna, molestie non purus in, viverra condimentum orci. Nulla a nunc mauris. Aliquam convallis interdum velit, aa
            </p>

            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='1998-12'>Dec '98</time>
            </div>
            <p>
                Sed volutpat purus enim, eget accumsan odio ullamcorper sit amet. Sed vitae imperdiet metus. Aenean mollis mauris odio, eget finibus ligula ornare eu. Aliquam id velit quis tellus cursus imperdiet. Mauris eget laoreet ipsum, sed ultricies magna. Aliquam vel neque ut risus dapibus suscipit nec nec ipsum. Nullam vulputate, elit sit amet finibus sagittis, nunc nisl molestie sem, et tincidunt neque magna in nunc. Nullam aliquam mi et ante dapibus posuere. Vivamus aliquet ipsum sit amet tellus lacinia, vitae convallis odio aliquam. Mauris rhoncus, leo sit amet vulputate placerat, sem tortor fermentum ex, quis luctus nulla sapien consequat nunc.
            </p>

            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='1999-12'>Dec '99</time>
            </div>
            <p>
                Phasellus a pellentesque urna. Integer eget mattis nulla. Nullam sed diam ipsum. Fusce interdum scelerisque arcu, quis ultricies risus accumsan vel. Quisque luctus nisi a nisl porttitor, at finibus elit porttitor. Fusce eget mauris a magna sollicitudin volutpat. Sed nisl magna, volutpat quis mauris a, sagittis mollis nibh. Ut consectetur justo et sem convallis, at elementum purus hendrerit. Curabitur eros odio, ullamcorper vitae facilisis vel, congue sed mauris. Aliquam egestas augue nec scelerisque ornare. Integer et neque metus. Suspendisse aliquet scelerisque odio et ornare. Donec ac mi sed nunc interdum aliquet nec at lectus. Praesent eu tortor pretium, euismod tellus ut, scelerisque massa. Nullam eleifend malesuada magna rutrum gravida.
            </p>

            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='2000-12'>Dec '00</time>
                </div>
            <p>
                Phasellus ultricies elit ac turpis consequat, a suscipit tellus cursus. Aenean in consectetur turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non dui non ipsum pretium sagittis. Donec dictum, enim sit amet venenatis venenatis, ante purus malesuada neque, ac pellentesque eros turpis eu velit. Vestibulum ligula leo, aliquet et dignissim et, dapibus nec orci. Nullam ultrices sapien id imperdiet aliquam. Vestibulum id lorem finibus, condimentum magna mollis, interdum magna. Sed vel lorem feugiat, aliquam mauris non, consequat ante. Nunc eu sem et dui porta auctor. Nam tincidunt orci sed egestas tempor. Suspendisse euismod, arcu vitae porta sollicitudin, justo erat porta sem, vel suscipit odio lorem sit amet mi. Maecenas quis finibus elit.
            </p>

            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='2001-12'>Dec '01</time>
            </div>
            <p>
                Praesent eu ante eu est rutrum suscipit. Maecenas dictum massa eros, blandit fermentum dui ultrices et. Duis in orci eget nulla tincidunt rhoncus at et purus. Nunc porta ipsum vitae lacinia ornare. Vivamus laoreet odio quis urna porta blandit. In viverra molestie ornare. Nam lorem turpis, lacinia at lacus non, pharetra efficitur ipsum. Donec ultrices lacinia velit id eleifend. Integer pellentesque lectus tincidunt est porta, et elementum ex euismod. Vivamus lobortis at odio at interdum. Vestibulum posuere quam dolor, at rhoncus elit cursus nec. Proin mollis tincidunt libero quis convallis. Donec vel placerat dui, at cursus urna. Donec cursus eleifend dapibus.
            </p>


            <div class='date-wrapper animate'>
                <time class='hide-date' datetime='2002-12'>Dec '02</time>
            </div>
            <p>
                Praesent eu ante eu est rutrum suscipit. Maecenas dictum massa eros, blandit fermentum dui ultrices et. Duis in orci eget nulla tincidunt rhoncus at et purus. Nunc porta ipsum vitae lacinia ornare. Vivamus laoreet odio quis urna porta blandit. In viverra molestie ornare. Nam lorem turpis, lacinia at lacus non, pharetra efficitur ipsum. Donec ultrices lacinia velit id eleifend. Integer pellentesque lectus tincidunt est porta, et elementum ex euismod. Vivamus lobortis at odio at interdum. Vestibulum posuere quam dolor, at rhoncus elit cursus nec. Proin mollis tincidunt libero quis convallis. Donec vel placerat dui, at cursus urna. Donec cursus eleifend dapibus.
            </p>
       </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
#timeline {
    width: 94%;
    height: 1%;
    margin: 1% 3%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #590C13;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

#path {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #424343;
    }

#marker {
    width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #ffffff;
    }

.date-wrapper {
    width: 0;
    max-width: 94%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 7%;
    left: 3%;
    }

time {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 -35px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6%;
    right:  0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #424343;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

.hide-date {
    visibility: hidden;
    }

p { /* This is place holder content used to test jQuery scroll position. Feel free to delete.  */
    padding: 3%;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 3em;
    }
```

Comment: which language is [this](http://dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/timeline/indexl.html)? Could you pleas share your code and explain the problem.

Comment: First of all, you are using invalid html. change `class='date-wrapper' class='animate'` to `class='date-wrapper animate'` when you want to add multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks! Although that did not fix my jQuery.

Comment: You forgot to tell what is your issue??? Error in console? Not expected behaviour? Etc...

Comment: There are no errors detected, but I want it to reveal the date associated with the element in the viewport. Right now, the jQuery is having trouble removing the class .hide-date, which has display: none;

Comment: No, please see my comments below.

Comment: Your monitor function never gets called... or do I miss something... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I think this is what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/SjF9p/37/

Changed your code to some extent. The main catch here is to identify which `<p>` tag is visible.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.visible = function(partial){

        var $t              = $(this),
            $w              = $(window),
            viewTop         = $w.scrollTop(),
            viewBottom      = viewTop + $w.height(),
            _top            = $t.offset().top,
            _bottom         = _top + $t.height(),
            compareTop      = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
            compareBottom   = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

        return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

                var updateMarker = function(ev) {
                    // Update measurements
                    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
                        contentHeight = $('#content1').height(),
                        pathWidth = $('#path').width(),
                        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

                    // Update #marker dimensions
                    var widthVal = scrollPosition/(contentHeight-viewportHeight)*pathWidth;
                    $('.animate').width(widthVal); 
                    // The breakdown: The line of code above defines scrollable distance by:
                    // Subtracting height of #content1 from height of viewport using (contentHeight-viewportHeight)
                    //This determines what percentage of the scroll has been scrolled through
                    // Multiply this percentage by #path width using *pathWidth
                    if(widthVal > 0) {
                        $('.date-wrapper').find('time').addClass('hide-date');                         

                        $("p").each(function(){
                            if($(this).visible(true)) {
                                $(this).prev().find('time').removeClass('hide-date');
                            }
                        });


                    } else
                       $('.date-wrapper').find('time').addClass('hide-date');                        
                }

                // Calls function when viewport is resized or scrolled    
                $(window).on('scroll resize', updateMarker);

                // Calls function on DOM ready
                updateMarker();

            });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I have a lot of time elements with .hide-date, and I only want the jQuery to act on the element when it is in view. Another problem might be that the CSS sets this class to display: none. I've also tried visibility hidden. Is it possible that since these aren't actually viewable in the viewport that it can't act on it using my if (visible) code?

Comment: Might be possible. Can you try this instead:

`if ($('.date-wrapper).is(':visible')) {
  $(this).find('time').removeClass('hide-date');
}`

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain how the code works? I'm trying to learn, but I could use a little help figuring it out.